# Have SSN masked in between the tags

Tags: java, regex

I have this program

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String subjectString = "<Name>DGAU</Name><SSN>123456789</SSN><OtherDetails></OtherDetails>";
        
        String REPLACE = "#";
        
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<SSN>\\d{9}");
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
        
        subjectString = regexMatcher.replaceAll(REPLACE);
        System.out.println(subjectString);
            
    }

}
```

When i run the above program

The Output formed is

```
<Name>DGAU</Name>#</SSN><OtherDetails></OtherDetails>
```

How to have output as

```
<Name>DGAU</Name><SSN>#</SSN><OtherDetails></OtherDetails>
```

Have the SSN # in between .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Regex

```
(<SSN>)\d{9}
```

and replace it with

```
$1#
```

[as shown here](https://regex101.com/r/FsDnE4/1)

[Code](https://regex101.com/r/FsDnE4/1/codegen?language=java)

**Explanation:**

- `(<SSN>)` - matches `<SSN>` and captures it in Group 1
- `\d{9}` - matches 9 digits

Now replace the entire match with `$1#` i.e, contents of Group 1 followed by `#`

Note: In Java, you need to escape `\` with another `\`. So, your regex is `(<SSN>)\\d{9}`